# PHP: How to combine logical operators

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have been working on a website for quite sometime, Right now im mostly doing work around the forums.
Here i have to tell php what to show and what not to show by certain conditions.

I use IF for this,
I also have it to work however the code becomes messy in the way i do it(Stacking IF`s).

When im trying to combine logical operators it doesnt work.
Im aware that you need todo something with parentheses though in this case im unsure where they should be placed.

```
if (
    isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] > 3 || 
    isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == $topic['author']
):
```

It will only take the first condition and ignores the second one

Comment: you should wrap `$_SESSION['role'] > 3 || isset($_SESSION['username'])` in brackets

Comment: I have given it a try, Unfortunately it dint work.

Comment: Was there something wrong with what you had? What were you expecting with what input vs what did you get?

Comment: What i originally did was simply stacking IFS it works but becomes rather messy especial when more condition need to be met.

In this case i want to check if there is a session if so compare that session to a value,
If that one doesn't meet the requirements do the same but with a different condition.

However when trying to pull this of in just 1 IF it just ignores the other condition du being 2 different comparison operators.

The option granted through here i have put to the test, Its the same story it ignores the other conditions.

Comment: Which conditions do you think are being "ignored" and what were the values of each of these variables when it hits the `if`?

Comment: everything after OR though i got it to work now, Not sure if its the correct way but it works thats what matters.

Answer (score 3):

Put parentheses around the `&&` expressions that tests whether a particular variable is set and then whether the value meets the criteria.

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] > 3) || 
    (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == $topic['author'])):
```

These parentheses aren't actually needed, since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. But I recommend using parentheses in any complicated conditions like this, to make the intent clear.

Note that an `||` condition is true if either of the operands is true. So if `role > 3`, it ignores the second condition. And if `username == author`, it ignores the first condition.

If you don't want to ignore either condition, you should be using `&&` rather than `||`.

Answer (score 1):

> It will only take the first condition and ignores the second one

When you have an `if` statement that stacks multiple conditions

```
if (
    -- condition 1 -- ||
    -- condition 2 -- ||
    -- etc --
) {
```

it will break out further checks when a condition is the first to pass.

E.g.

if we had this `$posted` array

```
[
    'user' => 'treybake',
    'name' => null
]
```

and use this `if`

```
if (
    !empty($_POST['user']) && $_POST['user'] !== 0 || 
    !empty($_POST['name'])
) {
    echo 'hello, world';
}
```

we will see an output of

> hello, world

this is because the check on `$_POST['user']` passed. Remember that `||` is `OR` - they both don't have to be true, only one or t'other.

If you want to build a conditional of required checks, use `&&` (`AND`).

However, I actually think this case is better off as separate if checks - easier to read and maintain, and less likely to go wrong.